# add padding for RTL content after use row_number CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables, css-counter, cellpadding

I used below CSS code for add row number to a table rows:

```
table {
    direction: rtl;
    counter-reset: line-number;
}

td:first-child {
    text-align: right !important;
}

td:first-child:before {
    content: counter(line-number) ".";
    counter-increment: line-number;
    padding-right: 0.3em;
    color: lightgray;
}
```

but it's content not align right after tenth row. See below image:

[image: row number padding issue]

But I want something like this:

[image: row_number2]

I also try add `padding` but it's not a working solution.

How fix this?

This is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5mfbmhm/) now.

Comment: What are you saying? Thats working as intended is it not? The number 10 will take up more room then 9 due to the extra digit. I'm not sure what your trying to get at.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I want to align above checkbox (or other content when using row number)

Comment: @Ruddy I add new image to my question.

Comment: I also add fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z5mfbmhm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `min-width` of `td:first-child:before`.

```
td:first-child:before {
content: counter(line-number) ".";
counter-increment: line-number;
padding-right: 0.3em;
color: lightgray;
min-width: 20px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately `min-width` not work for me. I also add fiddle see it: https://jsfiddle.net/z5mfbmhm/

Comment: Use updated css: `min-width: 20px;` `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the number in an element, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox"> <div class="number">10</div>
```

Then you can style that element, to have a minimum width:

```
.number {
   min-width:20px;
}
```

That way they have the same with, and you don't need funny `padding` depending on how many digits the number has.